# Разбить число на два множителя

Tags: python, алгоритм

К примеру, из числа 24 нужно будет получить
*[[6,4],[12,2],[3,8],[1,24]]*

Comment: Что значит "оптимальнее"? В чем состоит критерий оптимальности?

Comment: @AnT По скорости обычно понимается, иногда в учёт идёт ещё занимаемая алгоритмом память во время работы. В любом случае обычно оптимизируют и то и другое.

Comment: @Дмитрий Поляни: Формулировка вопроса сделана так, как будто существует какой-то критерий оптимальности самого разбиения.

Comment: @AnT да, я тоже так подумал сначала, но потом понял что разбиение на все варианты из 2-х делителей всего одно ))

Comment: @AnT согласен, надо написать не в группы по два, а на два множителя, если именно это имел ввиду автор

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чтоб было, с чем меряться оптимальностью :)

```
from math import sqrt

value = 24
res = []
for x in range(1, int(sqrt(value)+1)):
  if not (value % x):
     res.append([x,value//x])

print(res) # [[1, 24], [2, 12], [3, 8], [4, 6]]
```

Comment: Я перепишу под однострочник ? :)

Comment: @nick_gabpe `[[factor, number//factor] for factor in range(1, int(number**.5) + 1) if number % factor == 0]`

Comment: print [(d, n/d) for d in xrange(2, int(sqrt(n)+1) if not n % d ]

Comment: Ну, смотрю, оптимальности добавили :)

Comment: В питоне 3, / может float вернуть, поэтому мой пример использует //, чтобы целый результат получить. По мелочи: для большого number верхний предел неточный может быть `number=10**46` (хотя сам подход уже слишком медленный будет для таких чисел)

Comment: @jfs даже не может, а так, собака, и возвращает :) `type(4/2) >>>class  'float'>` исправил. Спс